# TemplateDoesNotExist django python

Tags: python, django

**Ошибка**

```
*TemplateDoesNotExist at /money/
../orders/templates/related/_related_submenu.html*

Template-loader postmortem
Django tried loading these templates, in this order:

Using engine django:

This engine did not provide a list of tried templates.
```

**html**
`money/templates/include/some.html`

```
{% include '../orders/templates/related/_related_submenu.html' %}>
```

есть приложение `money` и в нем надо импортировать шаблон из другого приложения `orders`. Как объяснить приложению `money`, что надо брать шаблон за пределами приложения?

Comment: Шаблоны общие для всех подключенных приложений `{% include 'related/_related_submenu.html' %}`

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [TemplateDoesNotExist из одного приложения в другое django python](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1285469/templatedoesnotexist-%d0%b8%d0%b7-%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b3%d0%be-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b8%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%b6%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%8f-%d0%b2-%d0%b4%d1%80%d1%83%d0%b3%d0%be%d0%b5-django-python)

Comment: В обратную сторону задубликатил, все-таки тут больше информации.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Django ищет шаблоны во всех `<app>/templates` и просто `templates` директориях. Если по какой то причине это не так, то фиксите настройки на те, которые вам нужны

```
TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [],  # Пути к папкам с шаблонами вне приложений
        'APP_DIRS': True,  # Искать в приложениях
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]
```

[Источник](https://metanit.com/python/django/2.5.php) , хотя можно найти и на официальной документации.

Это вам не php с его include'ами.

Путь к шаблону указывается относительно `templates`-папки, т.е. если хотите подключить шаблон `my_app => templates => my_app => my_model => detail.html` то **НЕ ЗАВИСИМО ОТ ПРИЛОЖЕНИЯ И ШАБЛОНА** в котором будете использовать этот шаблон, пишите `{% include 'my_app/my_model/detail.html' %}`. Никаких `../`